# org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) in onPostExecute as well as org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0

Tags: java, php, android, json

It has been days and I havent found any answer. And I am very new to android development. The problem I am facing is I keep on getting the error `org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0`  and `org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)` on my onPostExecute method

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String stringResult) {
    Log.e("DB", "" + stringResult);
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringResult);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (jsonArray != null) {
        mCallback.onSuccess(jsonArray);
        return;
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringResult);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (jsonObject != null) {
        mCallback.onSuccess(jsonObject);
        return;
    }

    mCallback.onFailed(stringResult);
}
```

the errors direct me to this **part**

```
try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringResult);
```

this **part** too

```
 try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringResult);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

as well as from the main class method

```
public class PostRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
```

please help me. thanks

Comment: Post the server response

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your response.

Comment: I tried jsonlint.com and this is what it returns

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 1:
@Overrideprotected 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: another error found:

Comment: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"result":"success","items":"10","username":"clar","name":"clar","user_id":"22","email":"clar@gmail.com","session":true} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think the code is not the problem as to why I cant seem to run the app. I have solved it. And the answer is not really found in what I have provided. Thanks anyway